# Image doesn't load the first time

Tags: java, image

I've been going on this example found online to write a similar program. It's load images the first time when you click on it in the Filechooser, but I have to do it twice before the image is display. I've tried putting the repaint elsewhere, but it doesn't work, but the window resizes to the image I'm trying to load.

Thanks!

```
 if(event.getSource() == menuitem1){

        dialog.setMode(FileDialog.LOAD);

        dialog.setVisible(true);

        try{
            if(!dialog.getFile().equals("")){
                File input = new File(dialog.getDirectory() + 
                    dialog.getFile()); 
                bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(input); 


                setSize(getInsets().left + getInsets().right + 
                    Math.max(400, bufferedImage.getWidth() + 60), 
                    getInsets().top + getInsets().bottom + 
                    Math.max(340, bufferedImage.getHeight() + 60));


                button1.setBounds(30, getHeight() - 30, 60, 20);
                button2.setBounds(100, getHeight() - 30, 60, 20);
                button3.setBounds(170, getHeight() - 30, 60, 20);
                button4.setBounds(240, getHeight() - 30, 60, 20);
                button5.setBounds(310, getHeight() - 30, 60, 20);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

public void paint(Graphics g) 
{
    if(bufferedImage != null){
        g.drawImage(bufferedImage, 
            getSize().width / 2 - bufferedImage.getWidth() / 2,
            getInsets().top + 20, this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try calling `paintComponent`

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); 
         if(bufferedImage != null){
            g.drawImage(bufferedImage, 
            getSize().width / 2 - bufferedImage.getWidth() / 2,
            getInsets().top + 20, this);
         }
 }
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Do you mean after the File statement?

Comment: I see what you mean. After the buttons. It still doesn't work, though.